# How To Apply Bounds in Unity For iOS devices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, unityscript

I've made an unity game for iOS devices. It has a game object(sphere) which moves by the force applied to it. But I want to limit the sphere within the screen bounds.

I've seen the unity reference to Bounds, but i don't know how apply it according to the iOS device screens. Please Help.

ThankYou.

Comment: why don't you put plans in the screen bounds and let the sphere collide?

Comment: @Roberto Plans? I don't get it. I've used cubes with box colliders around the sphere. but the sphere passes through it more often than not.

Comment: Ah, you never said you used boxes. Well, try changing the Collision Detection mode in the rigid body, try to make the cubes wider or use plans instead of cubes. Plans are relatively new, I think it came with Unity 4.

Comment: Does it detect the collision when the speed is low?

Comment: @Roberto Ya it detects collision at low speed upto the value of 30 at most but at higher speeds it passes through during the first collision.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21450378/in-unity-3d-4-3-collision-detection-is-not-working-there-are-two-objects-both

Comment: @Roberto sorry to say but that didn't helped me at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Mathf.clamp to keep your movement within the screen size.  This will be more efficient than using colliders on the edges of your screen.  Just play around with your object until you get the right numbers to keep it on your screen.  Of course if you plan to use iOS tablets etc you will need to be able to account for the change in your clamping area.

Here is a link to the Unity Documentation which actually includes an example of what you are trying to do.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html