# In Unity 3d 4.3, collision detection is not working. There are two objects, both objects have rigidbody component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using two objects both having rigidbody component.
But both object is not passing each other.

One object is used as platform using

```
road.Translate(0,0, -speedcal * Time.deltaTime);
```

using object.Translate method as soon as game starts like in Temple run.

Now in my game new road(platform object) generation is working fine.
But player and road is not colliding. they pas though each other.

Can anyone tell me how to work  collision detection or rigidbody together with object already Translating.

Comment: did both object are on the same layer? Or on layers that can collide with each other?

Comment: @Thaven my all objects have Default Layer do I need to change or add new layer?

Comment: Maybe "Is Trigger" is checked at one of the colliders

Comment: @Kay by default its unchecked and I am keeping it as it is

Answer (score 0):

I can think about three possible causes; check if you are in those situations:

- Your objects haven't a non-kinematic rigidbody attached. Consider that one of your objects has to exhibit a non-kinematic rigidbody attached, as told in the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).
- If you have configured the [Layer Collision Matrix](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/LayerBasedCollision.html) (*Edit->Project Settings->Physics*), you should check that both objects have are in the same layer, or that their layers can interact with each other (as Thaven told in his comment).
- Your velocity (`speedcal`) is really high, and you are encountering a "*bullet through paper*" problem. Basically, in this case, the velocity of an object is too high and the collision detection system cannot detect the intersection.

Comment: my speedcal starts from 25.0f to 50.0f
public float speedcal = 25.0f;

Comment: @RaviPal: if your velocity isn't high, you should check the first point of the list (it's a common mistake).

Comment: my game is like subway surfer and I m having problem in collision detection. My player is getting through the platform